# Example of Green's function solution to linear homogeneous differential equation subject to inhomogeneous boundary conditions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, education, boundary-value-problem, greens-function

**Context**

*Part A*

Generally, I like Handbook on Differential Equations by Zwillinger [1]. It seems to meet my needs most of the time. For example, from this book I was able to learn how to solve linear nonhomogeneous differential equation subject to homogeneous boundary conditions.  However, I can't seem to get my head around their explanation or their example regarding Green's function solutions to linear homogeneous differential equation subject to nonhomogeneous boundary conditions.

*Part B*

I have looked through this site for exemplary questions on this theme. I have found [2], [3], and [4] are related to this question to some extent. In [2], the question indeed revolves around the a homogeneous differential equation with nonhomogeneous Dirichlet boundary conditions. In fact, the differential operator that I use in this question is exactly the same as that appearing in [2]. There is an accepted answer in [2]. However, the answer there does not suit my needs. I cannot figure out what is being done, how come, and I can not generalize the results to more complex problems. In [3], the OP asks about the Cauchy problem. Again there is an answer but I am not able to generalize that answer to solve additional problems.  Thus, in my question below, I am asking for answers that adhere closely to what is found in [1] (see below). In [4], we have the same linear operator, but with mixed boundary conditions. There is an answer in [4], except that the answer includes the Green's function $G$ (i.e. a Green's function for the linear nonhomogeneous differential equation subject to homogeneous boundary conditions) rather than $g$ (i.e. a Green's function for the homogeneous differential equation subject to nonhomogeneous boundary conditions (see below)).

*Part C*

Here is what Zwillinger has to say on the matter. Please note that under fair use, I am copying verbatim from [1]:

> ``... suppose we want to solve the linear homogeneous differential equation
> subject to  inhomogeneous boundary conditions
> \begin{align}
> L\left[v\right] &=    0,
> \\
>  B [v] &= h(\mathbf{x}),\quad \mathbf{x}\in \partial \Omega. 
> \end{align}
> If we can solve
> \begin{align}
> L\left[g(\mathbf{x};\mathbf{z})\right] &=    0,
> \\
>  B [g(\mathbf{x};\mathbf{z})] &= \delta(\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{z}),
> \end{align}
> for $g(\mathbf{x},\mathbf{z})$, then the solution to the boundary value problem is given by
> $$ v(\mathbf{x}) =\int_\Omega g(\mathbf{x};\mathbf{z})h( \mathbf{z}) d\mathbf{z}. $$
> ... The conditions on $g(\mathbf{x};\mathbf{z})$ are ...
> (a) $L[g(\mathbf{x};\mathbf{z}) ] = 0$.
> (b) $B[g(\mathbf{x};\mathbf{z}) ] = 0$, except at $\mathbf{x}=\mathbf{z}$.
> (c) If $L[\cdot]$ is an $n$th order differential equation, then $g(\mathbf{x};\mathbf{z})$ must be continuous (with its derivatives up to order $n-2$) at $\mathbf{x}=\mathbf{z}$.
> (d) $\int_{\mathbf{z}^-}^{\mathbf{z}^+} B[g(\mathbf{x};\mathbf{z})]d\mathbf{x}=1.$

**Questions**

*Q.1*

How can I construct a Green's function, $g$, and use it solve the linear homogeneous differential equation for $\Phi(x)$ for $x \in [a,b]\subset\mathbb{R}$,
\begin{align}
\frac{d\Phi^2}{dx^2} &=    0,
\end{align}
subject to  inhomogeneous boundary conditions
\begin{align}
 &&B [\Phi] = \int_{\mathbb{R}} V_a\delta(x-a) + V_b\delta(x-b) dx   ?
\end{align}

*Q.2*

How can I show that the Green's function, $g$, satisfies the four conditions given in the block quote in the context?

*Q.3*

If there is, in fact, an error in the language in the block quote to make it correct, then can you explain what it it?

**Bibliography**

[1] Zwillinger and Dobrushkin, Handbook on Differential Equations, Fourth Edition, pp. 209-18.

[2] [Confusion about Green's functions for inhomogeneous boundary conditions but no forcing.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2573797/confusion-about-greens-functions-for-inhomogeneous-boundary-conditions-but-no-f)

[3] [Using Greens function to solve homogenous wave equation with inhomogeneous boundary conditions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4103202/using-greens-function-to-solve-homogenous-wave-equation-with-inhomogeneous-bound?rq=1)

[4] [How can a single Green's function be used in both the inhomogeneous and homogeneous versions of a differential equation?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1670556/how-can-a-single-greens-function-be-used-in-both-the-inhomogeneous-and-homogene?rq=1)